# NpgSql EntityFramework Core not persisting DateTimeOffset as UTC time in database

Tags: c#, postgresql, datetime, entity-framework-core, npgsql

I'm using `Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL 7.0.4` in my console app to persist `DateTimeOffset` to `PostgreSQL` Database. However the values stored in my database are always in `Local DateTimeOffset`. My local machine is configured with `IST` time zone which is `UTC +05.30`.

Here is my code,

`DbContext`:

```cs
public class TestContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Category> Categories { get; set; }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        optionsBuilder.UseNpgsql("Host=localhost;Database=EFDateTime;User id=postgres;Password=xxxx;")
                       .EnableSensitiveDataLogging()
                       .LogTo(Console.WriteLine, Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.LogLevel.Information);
    }
}
```

`Category`:

```cs
public class Category
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public DateTimeOffset DateTimeProperty { get; set; } = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow;
    public DateTimeOffset DateTimeOffsetProperty { get; set; } = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow;
}
```

I'm creating `new` `DbContext` and `new` `Category` and saving to database.

```cs
var context = new TestContext();
var category = new Category();
context.Categories.Add(category);
context.SaveChanges();
```

Now when I check the database, I can see `Local DateTimeOffset` with `+05.30` instead of UTC time with `+00.00`

Here is the query generated by EF Core,

```sql
info: 07-08-2023 16:32:19.239 RelationalEventId.CommandExecuted[20101] (Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command)
      Executed DbCommand (36ms) [Parameters=[@p0='2023-08-07T11:02:16.4694593+00:00' (DbType = DateTime), @p1='2023-08-07T11:02:16.4694577+00:00' (DbType = DateTime)], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
      INSERT INTO "Categories" ("DateTimeOffsetProperty", "DateTimeProperty")
      VALUES (@p0, @p1)
      RETURNING "Id";
```

Here is the screen shot,

[image: Date time Values stored in database]

If we see the highlighted values in above image, the values generated in the query is in `UTC` as expected but in database it is in `IST`.

| Value | DateTimeProperty | DateTimeOffsetProperty | Kind |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Query Generated | `2023-08-07T11:02:16.4694577+00:00` | `2023-08-07T11:02:16.4694593+00:00` | `UTC` |
| Database Persisted | `2023-08-07 16:32:16.469457+05:30` | `2023-08-07 16:32:16.469459+05:30` | `Local` |

Script Generated by EF Core command `Script-Migration`:

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "__EFMigrationsHistory" (
    "MigrationId" character varying(150) NOT NULL,
    "ProductVersion" character varying(32) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT "PK___EFMigrationsHistory" PRIMARY KEY ("MigrationId")
);

START TRANSACTION;

CREATE TABLE "Categories" (
    "Id" integer GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY,
    "DateTimeProperty" timestamp without time zone NOT NULL,
    "DateTimeOffsetProperty" timestamp with time zone NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT "PK_Categories" PRIMARY KEY ("Id")
);

INSERT INTO "__EFMigrationsHistory" ("MigrationId", "ProductVersion")
VALUES ('20230806181121_Initial', '7.0.9');

COMMIT;

START TRANSACTION;

ALTER TABLE "Categories" ALTER COLUMN "DateTimeProperty" TYPE timestamp with time zone;

INSERT INTO "__EFMigrationsHistory" ("MigrationId", "ProductVersion")
VALUES ('20230806181852_AddOffset', '7.0.9');

COMMIT;
```

Please can someone help me understand what I'm doing wrong? I would like to learn and  understand this.

Comment: Can you please share a Create SQL script for the `Categories` table? Perhaps, there is something wrong with time zone.

Comment: @DenisKiryanov I have updated the question with SQL Scripts

Comment: Could you please also check your db server time zone: `SELECT current_setting('TIMEZONE')`?

Comment: it shows `Asia/Calcutta`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> However the values stored in my database are always in Local DateTimeOffset

PostgreSQL does *not* store any timezone along with your timestamp, even though the type is called `timestamp with time zone`. That type simply holds UTC timestamps (by convention). The +05.30 time zone is being added for display purposes only when you select the value via a UI, based on your seesion's `TimeZone` parameter. You can change the `TimeZone` to be something else, at which point your UI will show the values in a different time zone; but the value stored in the database is *always* a UTC timestamp (for the `timestamp with time zone` type).

Note that `TimeZone` doesn't matter when you're using Npgsql to read the value back - it will always be read back as a UTC timestamp (e.g. DateTimeOffset with Offset=0). `TimeZone` only affects conversions of the timestamp to text, e.g. for display purposes.

It's recommend to give [this Npgsql doc page](https://www.npgsql.org/doc/types/datetime.html) a good read to better understand the mapping between .NET date/time types and PostgreSQL types, and also [this PG doc page](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-datetime.html) for more general information.

Comment: Ah interesting then the posgres client (pgadmin) I'm using is localised to show local date time offset. So then I can directly query using UTC datetime from my app?

Comment: It's not pgadmin that's localized - it simply requesting a textual representation from PG, and PG is the one applying the time zone conversion based on your session's `TimeZone`.

Comment: But yeah, when getting the value from your app (as opposed to from pgadmin), you'll just see UTC timestamps (assuming you're querying from `timestamp with time zone` columns and not `timestamp without time zone`). You can do `SET TimeZone='UTC'` in pgadmin to also make PG not convert there.

Comment: Awesome. Many thanks for clarifications and inputs. That helped a lot. Few days back I was confused with this behavior and I have asked another question related to this issue here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76818595/datetimes-are-stored-with-different-values-in-postgres-database-with-entity-fram . But if you see this question here different columns store in different format. Any clues?